# Cloud Run service gives 404 error when trying to access from hosted site

Tags: reactjs, firebase, go, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have set up a site using firebase hosting where I would like to send requests to an API to send emails. Locally, this works perfectly. However, after pushing the API using Google Cloud run, I had run into errors when trying to access the API online using the hosted site. I had used the following firebase tutorial to try and set this up.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#node.js_1

I was able to deploy it with no issues, however, when I try to access the API through POST requests, it returns a 404 error. The site itself was developed with React.JS and the backend API was developed using Golang.

firebase.json:

```
    {
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "api",
          "region": "europe-west1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JavaScript where the call to the API is being made:

```
const response = await fetch(this.state.endpoint+"/sendEmail", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            });
```

Golang router where the routing is being handled:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/sendEmail", SendEmail)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
```

Again, running this locally has no issues but running it on the cloud returns a 404 error.

**Update**

I have now fixed the issue that was pointed out by @guillaumeblaquiere, that was the issue to do with the code itself. I did not call the router and so the routing was not taking place. Below is the fixed version

```
log.Print("api: starting server")

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/sendEmail", SendEmail)

port := os.Getenv("PORT")
fmt.Println(port)
if port == "" {
    port = "8080"
}

log.Printf("api: listening on port %s", port)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), router))
```

The only issue left is that I have to call the API using the URL directly, not using rewrites.

Comment: What's the value of this `this.state.endpoint`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The endpoint is the entire URL + the API, so 'https://hosted-site.web.app/api'.

Comment: Can  you share the command that you use for deploying your Cloud Run service? Does your service work on this url `https://api-<random_hash>.run.app`? (step 3 in the deploy)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so the site is (https://rizbir-khan.web.app/) and the API is called 'api'. I used `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/rizbir-khan/api` to create the container image and `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/rizbir-khan/api --platform managed` to deploy the container image.

Comment: And what about the direct call to cloud run? Did you try a curl to the service url `https://api-<random_hash>.run.app`? Is it working?

Comment: nope, its not working either

Comment: Start by fixing this. If your Cloud Run service didn't answer, it's normal to have an error with firebase.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere have fixed the issue, the post is now updated to include the fix

Comment: Great!!! And now, still your issue with firebase?

Comment: no more issues, however there is one more which is that I have to call the API URL directly, not using the rewrites given

Comment: If the firebase dependency is up to date, it should work :(